# Работа с асинхронными запросами. JAVA

Tags: java, android

Значит, поставили задачу, нужно написать небольшое приложение под Android. Авторизация и получение какой-либо информации из базы Mysql с одного из серверов. 
Есть класс User, который будет получать информацию из базы.

```
public User(Context context){  

    Thread t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                Log.e("result", "Получаем данные");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        };
        t.start();
        t.join();

        Log.e("result", "Данные получены");
    }
```

Класс User Вызываю из MainActivity, при этом главный поток зависает и ждет выполнения нового потока, из-за t.join(). 
Вопрос: Как делать запросы чтобы не останавливать главный поток? И после получения данных, в MainActivity, была возможность работать с классом User. пример:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            User user = new User(this);
            Log.e("result", user.getFullName());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Синхронно никак не получится. Надо использовать колбэки. Вообще получение асинхронно данных из сети делается всякими либами. Есть стандартные решения типа `AsyncTask` (устарел), `Loaders` (сложная и непонятная х*рь); сторонние решения `Okhttp` (для вообще сетевых запросов), `Retrofit` (надстройка над `OkHttp` для `REST`).

Для работы с разными потоками можно ещё `RxJava` использовать.

А так да - в основном потоке запрос делать нельзя, тормозить основной поток нельзя (будет ANR через 5с).

Лично я советую `Okhttp` + `Retrofit` + `RxJava` - кратко и красиво и понятно выйдет в коде.